# Is there a way to mock a complete bit of code in pytest using mock?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

For instance, every time a test finds

```
database.db.session.using_bind("reader")
```

I want to remove the `using_bind("reader"))` and just work with

```
database.db.session
```

using mocker

Tried to use it like this in `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def session(mocker):
    mocker.patch('store.database.db.session.using_bind', return_value=_db.db.session)
```

But nothing has worked so far.

Code under test:

```
from store import database     
results = database.db.session.using_bind("reader").query(database.Order.id).join(database.Shop).filter(database.Shop.deleted == False).all(),
```

and I get

```
AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'using_bind' as an error.
```

Comment: Might need to see more of the code under test.  Where does it get `database` from?

Comment: @Samwise `from store import database
    results = database.db.session.using_bind("reader").query(database.Order.id).join(database.Shop).filter(database.Shop.deleted == False).all()`, and I get `AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'using_bind'` as an error. That's why I want to remove `using_bind`

Comment: Put it in the question with the right formatting, please, not all in one line in a comment.

Comment: @Samwise yup, sorry about that

Comment: The code would be easier to test if it were in a function instead of at the top level of the module -- as it is, it's going to execute as soon as you import the module, which makes it hard to set up the mocks correctly.

Comment: If you could move the code into a function, then you could do something along the lines of patching out `database` within the module under test, importing the real `store` in your test, and then setting `mock_database.db.session.using_bind.return_value = store.database.db.session` in your test before calling the function under test.  That way your mock's `using_bind` redirects to the real `store.database.session`.

Comment: @Samwise so once my code is in a function, lets say `def foo():` what can I set in my test `def test_foo(mocker):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with an MRE where the code under test uses a fake database:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class Session:
    def using_bind(self, bind):
        raise NotImplementedError(f"Can't bind {bind}")

    def query(self):
        return "success!"


database = Mock()
database.db.session = Session()


def code_under_test():
    return database.db.session.using_bind("reader").query()


def test():
    assert code_under_test() == "success!"
```

Running this test fails with:

```
E       NotImplementedError: Can't bind reader
```

So we want to mock `session.using_bind` in `code_under_test` so that it returns `session` -- that will make our test pass.

We do that using `patch`, like so:

```
@patch("test.database.db.session.using_bind")
def test(mock_bind):
    mock_bind.return_value = database.db.session
    assert code_under_test() == "success!"
```

Note that my code is in a file called `test.py`, so my `patch` call applies to the `test` module -- you will need to adjust this to point to the module under test in your own code.

Note also that I need to set up my mock *before* calling the code under test.